# Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{2\sqrt n\log n}\frac{\sin(2\pi b\sqrt n\log n+\pi b)}{\sin(\pi b)}-\frac1{2\sqrt n\log n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

Is there any method which I can apply to compute this limit?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1{2\sqrt n\log n}  \frac{\sin(2\pi b\sqrt n\log n+\pi b)}{\sin(\pi b)}-\frac1{2\sqrt n\log n}\,,$$

where $b\in \mathbb{R}$.

All suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Note that $|\sin x|\le1$ and use a comparison.

Comment: $b$ is a real, but specifically not an integer, I assume?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to make sense of the expression you should say that $b$ is not an integer. Now as $|\sin x|\leq 1$ and denominator goes to $\infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ so limits of both the elements in the sum is $0$. Now conclude that the limit is $0$.

Comment: Oh, @Jason has already provided a hint.